# How to automatically move the using directives inside the namespace on formatting?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Currently I have a .editorconfig in my VS setup which make the suggestion to move the using directives inside the namespace in C#. But sometimes it fails I don't know why. Could be a bad setting in VS?
Although my main concern is that I want the using directives to automatically move inside the namespace when formatting. Is this possible?

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 Version 16.9.0

Comment: I'm not sure about VS features and suggestions, although In Resharper you have Autocorrection in all files and suggestions when namespace is not defined well, but as far as i know it is not freeware..

Comment: what do you mean by "I want the using directives to automatically move inside the namespace when formatting" ?  are you wanting the location of an dll to move when formatting in ide?

Comment: Just move the using statements from outside to inside the namespace of the file I mean.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you configured the [csharp_using_directive_placement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0065) option.

There is currently [a bug open on the github roslyn project](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/35803) close to this subject. The bug is about misplaced new `using` directive added by refactoring (not moving the existing one).

You may open a feature request on the roslyn project.